# My sql file contains nonsense content

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have an sql file which was being used for SQLServer, my problem is that when I open the file it contains nothing but nonsense like so:

Iک}d9ے(csيIط)ص\‡)dٹ2_ئO§(µïu.=‹i’BWىأï¹1³ف™hىbژ/‚w&ح‚îِ†“zْàˆIQT)”edC¦e³´
¹ط!‎إ-Œ¤{^@.œ£HE÷ھ¸ٌqqœoة_`T‍kذم.°t/قژط½¾إé„t¾%م¶كىظq،f29ؤ
ھَl¤iٌ¾gi›¶¯ک3»«sـ°“c^r@^ـآg›çAچ/إ/±aNüط

Could you help me how I can fix it please?

Comment: You need to add alot more detail for us to help you. What sql file is this. What are you opening it with? How did you export it? What is the character encoding?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by what sql file is this? does it make difference if it is for mysql, sql server or sth else? it is simple sql file but I think it is encrypted, if yes, is it possible to decrypt it? Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I didn't export it, it is some database from some software, I want to see what's inside. Auto-Detect

Comment: Ah, well it came from software...what software? How was this imported, what coding language does the software use? Does those files always look this way? Why are you trying to decode the file? If you know the likely coding standards used,you might be able to translate...but it could be software proprietary language too.

Comment: I should also ask if you are using SSMS or another environment to run SQL Server. Some third party clients handle it differently (also makes stuff dependent on software). The blob could....could be true...but .SQL files are text format.

Comment: Was this really a SQL file? YES. Did it come externally? There was a program installed with that. Have you opened it in SSMS? YES. What folders did it come from? There was a program, when I installed that, I detected the database in the install direction, I want to see what's inside. Who was the original owner? Somebody else. Was the file part of a historic backup? NO. Is there any loss to discarding it? NO. How was Change Process Management accounted? I didn't get.

Comment: if you say `sql file`, do you mean a file with extension *.sql containing some standalone sql statements or the dump of a database (to be precise: a export)?

Comment: @clifton_h WOW Thanks. Software for education. I don't know it was installed with the main software. I don't know what you mean by always, yes it shows like those nonsense.

Comment: @Radinator Sorry, I don't know but the extension is sql and was installed with the main software. I guess it is just encrypted. Don't you think like so?

Comment: SQL files ARE text files, so this interests me. Cipher.exe could/maybe decipher crypted files, but the 3rd party software question can be important...If third part created it, can it read it? Or is this not an option. Trouble with client software is they can make it near impossible to use outside software

Comment: @clifton_h Now could you help me how I can decode using cipher?

Comment: @amateur: As you said: **There was a program installed with that.** and **was installed with the main software.** can you please tell us WHAT piece of software has "installed" this file on your pc?

Comment: @Radinator So let me explain: it is a software for students which contains all information about classes, teachers, students and so on... . It was an exe file that I installed. Is that enough? Thanks

Comment: Maybe. [Cipher - cmd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490878.aspx) really is for NTFS volumes, and a blind guess at that. Details. We need to know the program. The goal is to isolate the problem to know if A) SQL file is encryptrd by program, B) file encrypted by OS/registry, C) file written in alternate code read by program, D) file in wrong language format (like Japanese unicode), E) file is corrupted and worthless. A few more points could be added, but you see where I am going. That page should be helpful for the file OS encryption level...may not work on custom-set. :/

Comment: Without that program name or history...decoding stuff like this is generally considered improbable. Guessing at the format is equally frivolous of an attempt.

Comment: @amateur This software you speak of, does it have a name ? May we know this name ?

Comment: OK. This is my complete program not installed. I just copied, paste and pack it as rar file, here it is: http://s8.picofile.com/file/8267338192/DanaSetup.rar.html Thank You All :)

Comment: What's up guys? Have you got anything?

Comment: Still waiting... Have you got any good news?

Comment: Have you found anything :(

Comment: I shouldn't even be awake...but you need to put an example code in your question. No one would ever get an update without and anyone knew is less likely to open up rar files from a stranger.

Comment: @clifton_h Is it ok if I send you the sql file?

Answer (score 0):

It might be binary data.
Check if there is any BLOB column.

Comment: Is this an answer or a guess?

Comment: @Piyush How can I check that?

Comment: Is that inside insert / update statement.
How does the file begin ?

Comment: As I mentioned, it is nonsense like the one in my question.